# What is "find a solution accurate to within 10^-4 mean in Bisection method?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, rounding-error, bisection

If I for example after "9" iterations get the following :

p_9 = 1.365234375

and the actual p is given as:

p = 1.365230013

Is it simply saying that p_9 is within 10^-4 because the first 4 numbers **1.365** match up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely means
$$
\lvert p - p_9 \rvert < 10^{-4}
$$

Comment: So if i am understanding this, as long as the absolute error is less than or equal to some tolerance (10^-4) in this case then it is "within" that tolerance?

Answer (score 1):

In the bisection method, you have a bracketing interval $[a_k,b_k]$ that gets bisected in every step. As the exact point and the next midpoint are both inside this interval, the condition to check is 
$$
|b_k-a_k|<10^{-4},
$$
as the error is guaranteed to be smaller than that.